# Mathematical Analysis and Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have proven that if  $|x|<\varepsilon,\forall\varepsilon>0$, then  $x=0$. Further I have proven that ,$L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$ so that by definition $(\forall\varepsilon >0)(\exists N>0)(\forall n>N)\left|\frac{1}{n}-L\right|<\varepsilon$, but $\frac{1}{n}\ne 0, \forall n\in\mathbb N$.

Is there a contradiction or have I made an error in analysis?

Comment: I’m saying this intentionally harshly but intend no personal judgement. You, having 321 rep, have no excuse to not come up with a real title nor to not use MathJax. `@` me when you fix this, and I’ll undo my downvote.

Comment: What example do you give to new contributors? (:

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Is that directed to me? He’s obviously not a new contributor

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish, no, it was directed to the OP, because he still doesn't use LaTex. That only encourages new contributors to be sloppy. I would tag you if it were directed to you. 

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Ageeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not wrong nor you are arriving to contradiction. The deal with the first statement, is that $x$ is fixed, not matter which epsilon you take $|x|<\epsilon$. But in the other case, you are taking an $\epsilon$ and then finding that for some $N$ if $n>N$, $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$, you are not proving that for every $\epsilon>0$, $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, is subtle, but they are drastically different statements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction. You are getting $|\frac  1n |<\epsilon$ only under the extra condition $n >N$. If you had  $|\frac  1n |<\epsilon$ without any precondition you could say $\frac 1 n=0$ and get a contradiction, but that is not the case.

You should note that as $\epsilon$ becomes smaller and smaller the integer $N$ becomes larger and larger and you cannot have any $n$ which exceeds $N$ for all these values of $N$.